# hazelcast c++ client example keep crashing

Tags: c++, hazelcast

- I've tried to use hazelcast c++ in windows with the simplest example like

```
#include <hazelcast/client/HazelcastClient.h>

int main() {
    hazelcast::client::ClientConfig config;
    hazelcast::client::HazelcastClient hz(config);
    std::cout << "Started the Hazelcast C++ client instance " << hz.getName() << std::endl;
}
```

But it kept crashing

- I've downloaded "hazelcast-cpp-client-3.12.1-Windows_64" and compiled with visual studio 2019
- in the /bin directory I executed start.bat file and the server poped up and runs
- I writed code to test the connection (the code is like above) but it kept failed showing those message

  **In Client**

```
23/03/2020 18:23:37.421 INFO: [7436] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] (NOT_FOUND:NOT_FOUND) LifecycleService::LifecycleEvent STARTING
23/03/2020 18:23:37.421 INFO: [7436] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] LifecycleService::LifecycleEvent STARTED
23/03/2020 18:23:37.437 INFO: [12624] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] Trying to connect to Address[127.0.0.1:5701] as owner member
23/03/2020 18:23:37.437 INFO: [7120] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] ClientConnection{alive=0, connectionId=1, remoteEndpoint=null, lastReadTime=2020-03-23 09:23:37.462000, closedTime=2020-03-23 09:23:37.462000, connected server version=} closed. Reason: IOException {Connection closed by remote Error code:24} at TcpSocket::receive
23/03/2020 18:23:37.562 WARN: [12624] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] Exception during initial connection to Address[127.0.0.1:5701], exception ExecutionException {Could not be authenticated. Error code:19, Caused by:IOException {Packet not sent to null Error code:24} at AbstractClientInvocationService::send} at AuthenticationFuture::get
23/03/2020 18:23:37.562 WARN: [12624] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 2873 ms later, attempt 1 of 2.
23/03/2020 18:23:40.437 INFO: [12624] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] Trying to connect to Address[127.0.0.1:5701] as owner member
23/03/2020 18:23:40.437 INFO: [7120] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] ClientConnection{alive=0, connectionId=2, remoteEndpoint=null, lastReadTime=2020-03-23 09:23:40.458000, closedTime=2020-03-23 09:23:40.462000, connected server version=} closed. Reason: IOException {Connection closed by remote Error code:24} at TcpSocket::receive
23/03/2020 18:23:40.546 WARN: [12624] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] Exception during initial connection to Address[127.0.0.1:5701], exception ExecutionException {Could not be authenticated. Error code:19, Caused by:IOException {Packet not sent to null Error code:24} at AbstractClientInvocationService::send} at AuthenticationFuture::get
23/03/2020 18:23:40.546 WARN: [12624] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] Unable to get alive cluster connection, attempt 2 of 2.
23/03/2020 18:23:40.546 WARN: [12624] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] Could not connect to cluster, shutting down the client. Unable to connect to any address! The following addresses were tried: { Address[127.0.0.1:5701] , }
23/03/2020 18:23:40.546 INFO: [7436] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] LifecycleService::LifecycleEvent SHUTTING_DOWN
23/03/2020 18:23:41.328 INFO: [7436] hz.client_1[dev] [3.12.1] LifecycleService::LifecycleEvent SHUTDOWN
```

**In Server**

```
3 23, 2020 6:23:40 pm com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
경고: [172.16.253.101]:5701 [dev] [4.0] Connection[id=9, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:50518, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=false, connectionType=NONE] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=9, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:50518, qualifier=null, endpoint=null, alive=true, connectionType=NONE], thread=hz.heuristic_galileo.IO.thread-in-2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: CB2
        at com.hazelcast.internal.nio.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:116)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioPipeline.lambda$start$0(NioPipeline.java:127)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processTaskQueue(NioThread.java:354)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:289)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.run(NioThread.java:248)
```

Comment: at server level, we can see `Unknown protocol: CB2`. your Server does not recognize the Client protocol, and proceeds to close the sockets

Answer (score 2):

The cpp client for Hazelcast v4.0 is not yet released and 3.x version of client is not compatible with it. You may try to use Hazelcast 3.x in server for now.

Comment: Thanks I'll try 3.x server